# Perl Filename Naming Convention

Tags: perl, naming-conventions

What is the naming convention used to name a file with .pl extension(a file with perl code).
I can't seem to find this anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`.pl` actually stands for "Perl Library". The extension was originally used in Perl 4 where the only way to have reusable code was to `require` another Perl file. These days, we use Perl modules (with a `.pm` extension) for this.

It's unfortunate that using an extension for all Perl programs has become fashionable. People using your programs shouldn't be interested in the language that the program is written in. On all Unix-like operating systems, an extension is unnecessary as the shell can work out how to run a program by looking at the "shebang line" (`/usr/bin/perl`). Windows is the only popular operating system which doesn't use this technology.

Therefore my advice is to not use the `.pl` extension at all - unless you're writing code that is to be run on Windows.

Comment: Aren't .pl are automatically wrapped into .bat files on Windows and wrapped into extension-less bourne shell scripts on unix-like systems?

Comment: Can you please also tell if there is any common popular naming convention used to name the perl code files?

Comment: @AnkitChauhan: I don't really understand the question. What sort of thing do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an official convention, but personally:

- I do not name my perl scripts with .pl extension. (If I put these scripts in a Perl distribution for CPAN, the tool will handle Windows so Windows users can also run the script without having to specify any extension.
- I use all lowercase letters, with words separated by "-". Mixing lowercase and uppercase letters can be problematic on case-sensitive filesystems. Not using "-" will make words harder to read.

Additionally, I write my scripts with names in the form of "verb"+"object", e.g. "list-perl-releases", "create-user", and so on. And if a script only applies to my computer/laptop, I insert "my" somewhere in the name, e.g. "list-my-commits", "mount-my-google-drives".  But that's just my personal preference.